# Android app in play store has 2 versions the older and the new

Tags: android, react-native, ionic3, google-play

The problem that I am facing is that In the play store I have my version 1.0.0 of the app that is made in ionic 3, well next we have done a react native app of the same and we change the version to 2.0.0. Now the thing is that some users only see the last version while others the majority see the older one the 1.0.0. I don't know if this is related to this code of the build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "27.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 27
        targetSdkVersion = 27
        supportLibVersion = "27.1.1"
    }
 }
```

I think if i have the minSdkVerison to 16 it should work on all the android devices above that version but no. So maybe is not related to that can someone point me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance

UPDATE:
Here is my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.ionicframework.mdp365">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/icon"
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
      <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
          android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="Mdp365"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
      <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
       <meta-data
     android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
     android:value="AIzaSyB77i0i5NdDUjXluZHyXQNroi2qB4wduWQ"/>
     <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true"
        android:exported="false">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/filepaths" />
    </provider>

    <service android:name="io.invertase.firebase.messaging.RNFirebaseMessagingService">
    <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
    </intent-filter>
  </service>


    </application>

</manifest>
```

And here is my app build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"

import com.android.build.OutputFile

/**
 * The react.gradle file registers a task for each build variant (e.g. bundleDebugJsAndAssets
 * and bundleReleaseJsAndAssets).
 * These basically call `react-native bundle` with the correct arguments during the Android build
 * cycle. By default, bundleDebugJsAndAssets is skipped, as in debug/dev mode we prefer to load the
 * bundle directly from the development server. Below you can see all the possible configurations
 * and their defaults. If you decide to add a configuration block, make sure to add it before the
 * `apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"` line.
 *
 * project.ext.react = [
 *   // the name of the generated asset file containing your JS bundle
 *   bundleAssetName: "index.android.bundle",
 *
 *   // the entry file for bundle generation
 *   entryFile: "index.android.js",
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in debug mode
 *   bundleInDebug: false,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in release mode
 *   bundleInRelease: true,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in another build variant (if configured).
 *   // See http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Variants
 *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
 *   //         'bundleIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
 *   //         'bundleIn${buildType}'
 *   // bundleInFreeDebug: true,
 *   // bundleInPaidRelease: true,
 *   // bundleInBeta: true,
 *
 *   // whether to disable dev mode in custom build variants (by default only disabled in release)
 *   // for example: to disable dev mode in the staging build type (if configured)
 *   devDisabledInStaging: true,
 *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
 *   //         'devDisabledIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
 *   //         'devDisabledIn${buildType}'
 *
 *   // the root of your project, i.e. where "package.json" lives
 *   root: "../../",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in debug mode
 *   jsBundleDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in release mode
 *   jsBundleDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/release",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in debug mode
 *   resourcesDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in release mode
 *   resourcesDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/release",
 *
 *   // by default the gradle tasks are skipped if none of the JS files or assets change; this means
 *   // that we don't look at files in android/ or ios/ to determine whether the tasks are up to
 *   // date; if you have any other folders that you want to ignore for performance reasons (gradle
 *   // indexes the entire tree), add them here. Alternatively, if you have JS files in android/
 *   // for example, you might want to remove it from here.
 *   inputExcludes: ["android/**", "ios/**"],
 *
 *   // override which node gets called and with what additional arguments
 *   nodeExecutableAndArgs: ["node"],
 *
 *   // supply additional arguments to the packager
 *   extraPackagerArgs: []
 * ]
 */

project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "index.js"
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"

/**
 * Set this to true to create two separate APKs instead of one:
 *   - An APK that only works on ARM devices
 *   - An APK that only works on x86 devices
 * The advantage is the size of the APK is reduced by about 4MB.
 * Upload all the APKs to the Play Store and people will download
 * the correct one based on the CPU architecture of their device.
 */
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

/**
 * Run Proguard to shrink the Java bytecode in release builds.
 */
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

android {
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility 1.8
        targetCompatibility 1.8
    }

    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ionicframework.mdp365"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 3
        versionName "3.0"
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE')) {
                storeFile file(MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
                storePassword MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
                keyAlias MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
                keyPassword MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
            }
        }
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }



}

dependencies {
    compile project(':react-native-share')
    compile project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    compile project(':react-native-splash-screen')
    compile project(':react-native-oauth')
    compile project(':react-native-maps')
    compile project(':react-native-linear-gradient')
    compile project(':react-native-firebase')
    compile project(':react-native-fbsdk')
    implementation project(':react-native-firebase')
    implementation project(':react-native-maps')
    implementation project(':react-native-splash-screen')
    implementation project(':react-native-firebase')
    implementation(project(':react-native-maps')){
       exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-base'
       exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-maps'
   }
   implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.0'
    implementation project(':react-native-linear-gradient')
    implementation project(':react-native-fbsdk')
    implementation project(':react-native-oauth')
    implementation project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules

      implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.0.1"
  implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4"
    implementation 'me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.21@aar'
    //implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1"
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}
 apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
//com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin.config.disableVersionCheck = true
```

Here is my root project build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "27.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 27
        targetSdkVersion = 27
        supportLibVersion = "27.1.1"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'



        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories { 
        mavenLocal()
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
    }
}


task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '4.4'
    distributionUrl = distributionUrl.replace("bin", "all")
}
```

Comment: How is it possible to upload two apps with the same package name to the playstore? Did you name both the same? If they are already the same, the newer version should overwrite the existing one in store. It just needs a higher version number than the existing one. You can check these parts in your `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Comment: @schogges Yes they have the same name because the second is an update of the first and i upgrade the version also.The weird thing to me is that when you enter from the phone to some people show version 1.0.0 and others show version 2.0.0 the same app on the play store

Comment: If people are still using the older version of your app, they have to update it manually. As an option in PlayStore you can choose to automate or not, version updates of your apps. I'm sure the older version of your app is not accessible anymore, if it got an update. Of course your customers phones need to support your app by Android version to see your app in store.

Answer (score 0):

It is because of the new version support higher version than the version of users whom cant see the new update.

Comment: Do you know what should I do to fix it?

Comment: please add here the build.gradle for the two versions of app

Answer (score 0):

Since I can't update my comment anymore:

If people are still using the older version of your app, they have to update it manually. As an option in PlayStore you can choose to automate or not, version updates of your apps. I'm sure the older version of your app is not available anymore, if it got an update. Of course your customers phones need to support your app by Android version to see your app in store.

Responsible for this is your `minSdkversion`.
It tells the Store which Android API version is min required on the users phone. Your `minSdkversion` (16) is API version 16 which is Android Version 4.1.x - Codename `Jelly Bean`.

Answer (score 0):

When publishing your app you should deactivate the APK of the old version (version 1) and only have version 2 active. Then everyone will get version 2.

However, if some users are seeing version 1 it means version 2 is not compatible with their phone, as Play will not deliver an incompatible APK. You might want to investigate why that is. We can only help you if you post your `AndroidManifest.xml` file and your build.gradle.

Comment: I posted my files in the question above.